How do I pass arguments to a globally registered plugin in ng2-charts (alternatively, how do I register it locally)?
I have the following problem with ng2-charts (version 4.1.1, chart.js being version 4.4.0): I made a plugin to color different parts of a line chart according to some threshold values. I got help from this question for the plugin implementation. The thresholds are passed as input variables to the component which contains the chart. I need to instantiate multiple charts at the same time (imagine them on a dashboard, in a sort of grid layout), having different thresholds for each of them.
The problem is that, since the plugin I made is registered globally within Chart.js, it seems that the threshold values it gets are the ones passed first, for all the charts, even if I'm using this to refer to the instance variables of the class (and those do get updated). E.g., I have two charts, the first receives minThreshold: 10, maxThreshold: 20, the second minThreshold: 20, maxThreshold: 40, but the plugin considers 10 and 20 for both.
Just to explain a little bit the code, updateDataPointsColor is responsible of coloring the points laying on the linechart. I'm also using the annotation plugin to render a dashed horizontal line to represent the thresholds and, by the way, the interesting thing is that, though the latter plugin is registered globally, it is able to obtain dynamically the values of the thresholds as I update them in the options object. I'd like to do the same with my plugin or, alternatively (if it makes sense), register it locally (but I couldn't seem to make it work).
Does anybody have any suggestions or idea about how to solve the issue?
Here's my code:
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartDataset, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';


@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  get data(): any[] { return this._data; }
  set data(data: any[]) {
    this._data = data;
    this.updateDataPointsColor();
    this.updateChart();
  }
  private _data!: any[];

  @Input()
  get yAxes(): any { return this._yAxes; }
  set yAxes(yAxes: any) {
    this._yAxes = yAxes;
    this.lineChartOptions.scales['y'] = this._yAxes;
    this.updateDataPointsColor();
    this.updateChart();
  }
  private _yAxes: any;

  @Input()
  maxThreshold: number = undefined;

  @Input()
  minThreshold: number = undefined;

  @Output() onCloseChartsDashlet: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  display: boolean = true;
  destroyed: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart!: BaseChartDirective;

  // contains _data array
  public lineChartData: ChartDataset[];

  public lineChartLabels: any[];

  public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Time',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            size: 14
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          padding: 10
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
        }
      }
    },
    datasets: {
      line: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        tension: 0.1
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            display: this.minThreshold ? true : false,
            type: 'line',
            id: 'minThreshold',
            scaleID: 'y',
            value: this.minThreshold,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw'
          },
          {
            display: this.maxThreshold ? true : false,
            type: 'line',
            id: 'maxThreshold',
            scaleID: 'y',
            value: this.maxThreshold,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw'
           },          
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  public lineChartLegend = false;
  public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';

  public chartName = null;


  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    Chart.register(annotationPlugin);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.minThreshold ||
        changes.maxThreshold) {

      if (changes.minThreshold) {
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].value = this.minThreshold;
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].display = this.minThreshold ? true : false;
      } else {
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[1].value = this.maxThreshold;
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[1].display = this.maxThreshold ? true : false;
      }

      if (this.minThreshold !== undefined ||
          this.maxThreshold !== undefined) {
        this.registerPlugins();
        this.updateDataPointsColor();
        this.updateChart();
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    //console.log("chart destroyed");
  }


  /**
   * Set data labels
   */
  private setLabels() {
    // do something
  }

  /**
   * Update chart with new data
   */
  updateChart() {

    this.lineChartData = [{
      data: this._data.map(el => {
        return {
          x: el.timestamp,
          y: el.value
        }
      }),
      fill: false
    }];
    this.setLabels();
    this.chart?.update();
  }

  /**
   * Change some data points color upon a condition
   */
  updateDataPointsColor() {

    let dataColors = this.lineChartOptions.datasets.line;
    let colorsArray: any = [];
    for (const dataPoint of this.data) {
      let color = 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)';
      if (dataPoint.value >= this.maxThreshold ||
          dataPoint.value <= this.minThreshold) {
        color = 'red';
      }
      colorsArray.push(color);
    }
    dataColors.pointBackgroundColor = colorsArray;
    dataColors.pointHoverBorderColor = colorsArray;
  }

  private registerPlugins() {
    Chart.register(
      {
        id: "color-by-min-max-thresholds",
        afterLayout: chart => {
          if (!this.maxThreshold || !this.minThreshold) {
            return;
          }
          let ctx = chart.ctx;
          ctx.save();
          let yAxis = chart.scales["y"];
          let yThresholdMax = this.maxThreshold ? yAxis.getPixelForValue(this.maxThreshold) : undefined;
          let yThresholdMin = this.minThreshold ? yAxis.getPixelForValue(this.minThreshold) : undefined;

          let offsetMax = yThresholdMax ? (yThresholdMax - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top) : 0;
          let offsetMin = yThresholdMin ? (yThresholdMin - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top) : 1;
      
          if (offsetMax < 0) {
            offsetMax = 0;
          } else if (offsetMax > 1) {
            offsetMax = 1;
          }

          if (offsetMin < 0) {
            offsetMin = 0;
          } else if (offsetMin > 1) {
            offsetMin = 1;
          }

          let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yAxis.top, 0, yAxis.bottom);
          gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
          gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'red');
          gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)');
          gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin, 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)');
          gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin, 'red');
          gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red');
          chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = gradient;
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    );
  }

}

Another thing I didn't understand is that I was "forced" to use the OnChanges hook to call registerPlugins because, otherwise, the values of the thresholds would be undefined (I tried registering the plugin both in ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit, but with no success; in the hooks the values were set, but in the plugin function they were undefined).

While generating the datasets you can pass the variable with a value,
but you have to make it any type, for example:
public lineChartData: any = {
  labels: [10, 20, 30],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "hi",
      data: [10, 20, 30],
      circumference: 180,
      rotation: 270,
      **someVariable**: 20
    },
  ],
};

Then you can access it in your custom plugins, for example:
needleValue = 100
customPlugin = {
  id: "gaugeNeedle",
  afterDatasetsDraw(chart: any, args: any, plugins: any) {
    const { ctx, data } = chart //data will have detasets
  }
}


Following another user's answer, posted some time ago, which now seems to have been deleted, I solved the issue by declaring the custom plugin as a constant out of the component, and defining/updating the threshold values in the lineChartOptions object within the ngOnChanges hook. Below is a code example.
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartDataset, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';


const colorByMinMaxThresholds = {
  id: "color-by-min-max-thresholds",
  afterLayout: chart => {
    const options = chart.options;
    const minThreshold = options.plugins.minThreshold;
    const maxThreshold = options.plugins.maxThreshold;
    if (!minThreshold || !maxThreshold) {
      return;
    }
    let ctx = chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    let yAxis = chart.scales["y"];
    let yThresholdMax = maxThreshold ? yAxis.getPixelForValue(maxThreshold) : undefined;
    let yThresholdMin = minThreshold ? yAxis.getPixelForValue(minThreshold) : undefined;

    let offsetMax = yThresholdMax ? (yThresholdMax - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top) : 0;
    let offsetMin = yThresholdMin ? (yThresholdMin - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top) : 1;

    if (offsetMax < 0) {
      offsetMax = 0;
    } else if (offsetMax > 1) {
      offsetMax = 1;
    }

    if (offsetMin < 0) {
      offsetMin = 0;
    } else if (offsetMin > 1) {
      offsetMin = 1;
    }

    let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yAxis.top, 0, yAxis.bottom);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin, 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red');
    chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = gradient;
    ctx.restore();
};

@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  get data(): any[] { return this._data; }
  set data(data: any[]) {
    this._data = data;
    this.updateDataPointsColor();
    this.updateChart();
  }
  private _data!: any[];

  @Input()
  get yAxes(): any { return this._yAxes; }
  set yAxes(yAxes: any) {
    this._yAxes = yAxes;
    this.lineChartOptions.scales['y'] = this._yAxes;
    this.updateDataPointsColor();
    this.updateChart();
  }
  private _yAxes: any;

  @Input()
  maxThreshold: number = undefined;

  @Input()
  minThreshold: number = undefined;

  @Output() onCloseChartsDashlet: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  display: boolean = true;
  destroyed: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart!: BaseChartDirective;

  // contains _data array
  public lineChartData: ChartDataset[];

  public lineChartLabels: any[];

  public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Time',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            size: 14
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          display: true,
          padding: 10
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
        }
      }
    },
    datasets: {
      line: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)',
        tension: 0.1
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            display: this.minThreshold ? true : false,
            type: 'line',
            id: 'minThreshold',
            scaleID: 'y',
            value: this.minThreshold,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw'
          },
          {
            display: this.maxThreshold ? true : false,
            type: 'line',
            id: 'maxThreshold',
            scaleID: 'y',
            value: this.maxThreshold,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw'
           },          
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  public lineChartLegend = false;
  public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';

  public chartName = null;


  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    Chart.register(
      annotationPlugin,
      colorByMinMaxThresholds
    );
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.minThreshold ||
        changes.maxThreshold) {

      if (changes.minThreshold) {
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].value = this.minThreshold;
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].display = this.minThreshold ? true : false;
      } else {
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[1].value = this.maxThreshold;
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins.annotation.annotations[1].display = this.maxThreshold ? true : false;
      }

      if (this.minThreshold !== undefined ||
          this.maxThreshold !== undefined) {
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins["minThreshold"] = this.minThreshold;
        this.lineChartOptions.plugins["maxThreshold"] = this.maxThreshold;
        this.updateDataPointsColor();
        this.chart?.update();
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    //console.log("chart destroyed");
  }


  /**
   * Set data labels
   */
  private setLabels() {
    // do something
  }

  /**
   * Update chart with new data
   */
  updateChart() {

    this.lineChartData = [{
      data: this._data.map(el => {
        return {
          x: el.timestamp,
          y: el.value
        }
      }),
      fill: false
    }];
    this.setLabels();
    this.chart?.update();
  }

  /**
   * Change some data points color upon a condition
   */
  updateDataPointsColor() {

    let dataColors = this.lineChartOptions.datasets.line;
    let colorsArray: any = [];
    for (const dataPoint of this.data) {
      let color = 'rgba(31, 119, 180, 1)';
      if (dataPoint.value >= this.maxThreshold ||
          dataPoint.value <= this.minThreshold) {
        color = 'red';
      }
      colorsArray.push(color);
    }
    dataColors.pointBackgroundColor = colorsArray;
    dataColors.pointHoverBorderColor = colorsArray;
  }
}

